# MAX10 Flash and separating NIOS Firmware from FPGA config for remote updates

Tags: flash, intel-fpga, max10

I'm trying to get to grips with how MAX10 memories work, especially if you want to split firmware and FPGA config into completely separate sections. I have read and reread the MAX memory guide, but I'm unclear about several things.

Although Altera/Intel call memories UFM for user flash memory (for firmware and/or user data)  and CFM for configuration flash memory (for FPGA configuration), it seems they are loose terms and that you can store firmware in the CFM.

In our case there is a desire to split the FPGA and NIOS firmware so that it's possible to upgrade NIOS firmware and the FPGA config separately. The FPGA config is largely stable and most of the changes now will be to the firmware that the NIOS processor runs.

So, the first question is: is this even possible? Do you have to update both the FPGA config and the NIOS code together?

If it is possible, how would/could this work?

Could we:

Have a never-to-be-changed image (I *think* that's what people refer to as a golden image) in CFM0 that comprised of a simple NIOS core *and* its firmware that downloads new firmware images into UFM0 and UFM1 and/or FPGA config into CFM1 and 2? Or can a firmware image only fit in either UFM0 *or* UFM1?

One thing that concerns me is that the NIOS projects seem to be very bloaty. Even a simple hello world program takes up 24k program memory from what I can make out. If that's the case we're soon going to run out of UFM space if you can only use a single 32k block per program. This would suggest you're better off keeping the NIOS code in with the FPGA config and storing it in CFM, but that might mean you can't upgrade firmware separately to config data.

Which leads me on to external flash. In the documentation it suggests using external flash for the firmware if the program is going to grow too big. It has been suggested to me that the MAX10 only works with certain flash chips for booting, and if that's the case (I can't find anything to confirm or deny this), would we possibly be painting ourselves into a corner when a flash chip is made obsolete (which they regularly are). I appreciate there may be Altera-specific config devices that they'd keep going for the life of MAX10s, but then would you be able to store extra user data in those that could be pulled out by firmware the NIOS processor runs in normal operation?

Comment: These are all very good questions. I see the post is very old. Did you get any answers on these topics since I am facing the same type of application.

Comment: Well, I never got good answers and the project has ended for me, thankfully. However, the long and short of it is, you don't have to update both at the same time.You can mix and match what goes where in these devices, which IMNSHO makes their nomenclature daft. 

I was still left with the distinct impression though that unless your app was really small, you were going to struggle and would need to use external memory for a second image, having an SPI driver in your bootloader and loading it into RAM.

Comment: My advice FWIW is to get an Altera expert in for a month or two to teach you how to do this. I ended up working with one who said that the Altera docuemtation is dire and only gets worse with Intel having taken over. You'll save yourself so much money in the long run if you get someone to teach you how to do this. 

Even better, unless you really, really have to use a softcore processor. Don't.